# Magento how to clone the custom collection

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need to clone my custom collection.

When I'm using the *clone* it makes it as reference.

In the example below the $myCollection will have the same Select as the cloned on:

```
$cloneCollection = clone $myCollection;
$cloneCollection->addFieldToFilter('my_field', 'my_value');
```

PS. I saw that you can clone some core collections this way, but it wont work for the custom collections for some reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$cloneCollection = clone $myCollection;
$cloneCollection->clear();
$cloneCollection->addFieldToFilter('my_field', 'my_value');
```

hope this help you